# How to setup Visual Studio/JetBrains Rider for interpreter development in F#?

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2017, fsyacc, fslex

For a while now I have been experiencing issues with configuring IDE`s (Visual Studio and JetBrains Rider) to include FsLexYacc packages and etc. to start learning interpreter development. I have been following [this guide](http://fsprojects.github.io/FsLexYacc/fslex.html) at GitHub of how to add configurations into .fsproj file, but my VS 2017 crashed with an issue of unrecognized tag FsYacc. 
Also I have been searching for online templates, there were non available. Maybe some of you have been experiencing the same problem and found a solution and could help me ?

Edited: the error that IDE is throwing when I update the .fsproj file:

```
Project 'Test' load failed: The element <FsYacc> beneath element <Project> is unrecognized.  D:\RiderProjects\Test\Test\Test.fsproj
```

Comment: The FsLexYacc package is now at version 7.0.6, have you checked that the import path you added to the fsproj points to the targets file, and that the import comes before the FsYacc tag? (Also, if you added the package using paket, the version won't be included in the path at all).

Comment: @marklam I added packages using NuGet and yeah the version was 7.0.6. The import tag came before the FsLex and FsYacc tags. I think the problem is that those tags need to go under ItemsGroup tag